# What is the purpose of the mosquito?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, creation, bugs

Everything created was created for the purpose of serving G-d's ultimate plan for his creation which is to acknowledge G-d. What lesson or use can we make from mosquitos?

Comment: Can you [edit] in a source for your opening assertion? Can you [edit] in more information about why you're interested in a lesson from mosquitos, in particular?

Comment: In [this RadioLab episode](http://www.radiolab.org/story/kill-em-all/), one of the guest scientists makes the intriguing suggestion that a major benefit of mosquitos is that they've kept pesky humans, for a long time at least, from invading and destroying rain forests. After listening to that episode, I was considering posting a question here about whether Judaism has a stance on humanity choosing to eradicate a particular species.

Comment: That Hashem needed annoying insects despite the trouble they cause so we can learn and tolerate people who annoy us (whom Hashem also created).

Comment: To spread malaria and west nile virus and in general to pester and bother people and animals.

Comment: http://www.shturem.org/index.php?section=news&id=72880

Comment: @Yishai As they say -- you can learn something from everything: either what to do, or what not to do! (also, you have an answer.....)

Comment: @Shokhet, there is a better answer though. A Medrash where Dovid HaMelech specifically wonders the purpose of a Mosquito and gets his answer when a mosquito bite moves a guards leg out of the way so he can escape. I just couldn't find it, but perhaps someone else will. (Also, pace that article, I'm not sure a יתוש is in fact a mosquito, and not a similarly small insect, like a flea).

Comment: @Yishai Thought that story was about a spider, and a spider spins a web over a cave where he's hiding from Shaul.....

Comment: @Shokhet, yes, that too. I remember three creatures, the spider, the mosquito and a third one (that I don't remember which).

Comment: @Yishai The שוטה? (and he pretends to be crazy so his life is saved? לדוד בשנותו את טעמו לפני אבימלך [Psalms 34]?) .....come to think of it, it might be the medrash there that discusses this.

Comment: @Shokhet, yes, that let me find [a reference](http://ronypony.blogspot.com/2014/07/water-water-insanity-and-torah-thought.html), although there it goes with wasp, not mosquito. I would need to look it up, but no time now.

Comment: @Yishai I was about to mention that yitosh is usually translated as gnat. I also remember the medrashim with David and the achbash and shoteh, but not the mosquito.

Comment: @Shokhet, [source found](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9) and it is not a mosquito.

Comment: @user6591, reading wikipedia there not much of a difference between (some types of) a gnat and a mosquito (unlike a flea which is wingless). Is there a distinctive word in pre-modern Hebrew for a mosquito that is different from a gnat?

Comment: @Yishai rebi alufai umiyudai! We always call those little fruit fly type bugs gnats. I always associated them with the chazal about yitosh, the Titus story for instance. But now you have proven that incorrect! Live and learn man, live and learn.

Comment: @Yishai and calling a blood sucker a machnis vi'eino motzi is really spot on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yishai left a [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45830/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-mosquito?noredirect=1#comment121714_45830) with a link to an [article](http://www.shturem.org/index.php?section=news&id=72880), in which the Lubavitcher Rebbe remarks that the mosquito is a creature that only takes, and doesn't give....

> The mosquito does serve somewhat as a giver, the Rebbe explained. Its
>   contribution is the lesson it provides for us. The mosquito is the one
>   who teaches us the very concept that to be a G-dly creature in this
>   world you must contribute!

You can learn a lesson from everything you see -- either what to do, or what *not* to do!
(~ a wise friend)

Comment: If this is good logic, then it is tautological that everything in the world serves a purpose. I always assumed the latter claim was more meaningful than that

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Not sure which part you're confused about :)

Comment: @DoubleAA I understood the phrase "everything in the world serves a purpose" :P ......I still don't understand the meaning of your comment.

Comment: He means that this has given automatic purpose to anything that exists, and therefore removes significant meaning from saying that everything has a purpose. (I think.) cc @DoubleAA

Comment: @DoubleAA If the argument was "No Jewish philosopher could find a purpose for the mosquito, and the Lubavitcher Rebbe deduced form here that its purpose is to show that everything has a purpose, even if that purpose is only to show that everything has a purpose." I'd agree with you. But this is more subtle: it's that the mosquito has no practical constructive purpose (different from no purpose for its creation) [and is ungodly] and thus teaches that to be godly you have to have a practical constructive purpose -- & that teaching is the purpose for its creation. Doesn't seem tautological to me.

Comment: Shokhet, does he explain how he knows that the mosquito is ungodly (whatever that means)? (Cf. my previous comment.)

Comment: @msh210 Not exactly sure....look at what's written there....he says that it is "detestable" and "the most loathsome creature around," based on a midrash (Bamidbar Rabbah 18:22) "[b]ecause he imbibes, but does not excrete" (which I assume means that it is a taker, and not a giver)

Comment: @msh210, although the article only alludes to it, it is a reference to [Tanya chapter 24](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/tanya/1/24) יתוש שמכניס ואינו מוציא שהיא קליפ' היותר תחתונה ורחוקה מבחי' הקדושה המשפעת בתכלית הריחוק

Comment: Shokhet, @Yishai, bleagh. That means the argument is "A mosquito is a pure taker sans practical purpose; thus, it's ungodly; thus, it's existence serves the purpose of showing that everything godly has a practical purpose." which I agree with DoubleAA is tautological: if we didn't already know everything godly has a practical purpose (which is what we're learning) then we wouldn't know the mosquito's ungodly & the whole argument would fall apart.

Comment: @msh210, un-G-dly does not mean "without practical purpose". You are conflating two different points. The article is about being a giver (a basic quality of G-dliness), not about defending the purpose of a mosquito. The answer extends that into therefore serving a purpose (it teaches a lesson).

Answer (score 10):

This is adressed in the Tiferes Yisroel on Avos, ch. 4 mishna 3, oisios 20 & 21.

The mishna says ואל תהי מפליג מכל דבר, don't be seperated from anything. The T.Y. explains this to mean not to question any of Hashems creations and to assume there is a good reason for them, even if we don't know the reason. He singles out the fly the gnat and snakes and scorpions as questionable being that they bite and are bothersome. He says that flies and gnat help in so far as their flying around helps move stale air, therefore in hot humid places we find more of these bugs. 
End quote.

We perhaps won't appreciate his scientific explenation nowadays but his basic intent still stands.

Answer (score 1):

the purpose of nature is to provide a misleading appearance that the world carries itself. Therefore, when nature was created, with it came the loopholes for interpreting the world according to the view that the universe always carried itself. Even though, it was 5 minutes old, Adam looked like a 30 year old man. Likewise, the light from stars millions of light years away reached the Earth. It is part of the creation of nature.

This is why we have evidence in nature of common ancestry (chromosome fusion, viral DNA, etc.), or that the world appears billions of years old as a result of some cosmological accident, etc. etc. Likewise, we have things which don't seem to be of use to man, such as mosquitos, deep-sea creatures, or a vast universe.

source: based mostly on some lectures I heard from Rabbi Dovid Gottlieb

Comment: Is this answer claiming that there is no particular significance to the existence of mosquitoes - that they are solely a consequence of the patterns of behavior in the natural world (which look to us like natural laws)?

Comment: related? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/i-know-a-and-based-on-a-im-asking-b

Comment: @IsaacMoses there may be other purposes, as other answers pointed out, but the point is that there does not have to be a particular purpose for each and every specie or aspect of creation as the OP seems to assume

Answer (score -1):

Mosquitoes exist to feed the bats.

All animals have a place in the food-chain.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Is this your own idea or can you [edit] in a source that this is why according to Judaism?  Thanks.